# if-statement with OR and NOT conditions combined

Tags: objective-c

So this is probably a silly question for anyone with decent knowledge of Objective-C.

I have an `if-statement` where I check if the `NSString` equals anything **but** "John" or "Michael".

I tried the following code and it didn't work.

```
if (![selectedName isEqualToString:@"John"] || ![valtNamn isEqualToString:@"Michael"]) {
    // DO SOMETHING    
}
```

However this does work

```
if ([selectedName isEqualToString:@"John"] || ![valtNamn isEqualToString:@"Michael"]) {
    // DONT DO ANYTHING    
} else {
    //DO SOMETHING  
}
```

What am I'm missing about using `NOT` together with `OR`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The negation of condition "John or Michael" should be

```
!([selectedName isEqualToString:@"John"] || [valtNamn isEqualToString:@"Michael"])
```

(not (John or Michael))

or, in other words (see the AND instead of OR)

```
![selectedName isEqualToString:@"John"] && ![valtNamn isEqualToString:@"Michael"]
```

(not John and not Michael)

This should be obvious but it is also formally described in logic by [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

To understand this, you can simplify it a bit:

```
BOOL isJohn = [selectedName isEqualToString:@"John"];
BOOL isMichael = [selectedName isEqualToString:@"Michael"];

if (!isJohn && !isMichael) {
  //do something
}
```

The condition you have written actually means "if it's not Michael or if it's not John", or "not (John and Michael)" and evaluates always to `YES` since the name cannot be "John" and "Michael" at the same time.

Comment: Of course, the !-sign was placed on the wrong side of the condition. Thanks!